# Get Clicks per Second for a Button

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get the clicks per second for a Button and save it in `_clicksPerSecond`.

I already got how many clicks the user did:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  _klicks++;
}
```

So, if i click on the button, the counter for a click goes up one, that value will be saved in a `Highscore.txt` file:

```
writeHighscore = _klicks + Environment.NewLine;
File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(savePath, "Highscore.txt"), writeHighscore);
```

What i need is to count how many `_klicks` the user did in a *second*. But I don't know how to get the Time and how to get the value of `_klicks` just for the second. For now i only get the `_klicks` the user made all time.

I'm using a WPF-Project for that.

Comment: Save the start time and the end time. That's the trick

Comment: what about DateTime.Now?

Comment: @bamanow How to get only a second with that? So if the user clicks the Button, i call DateTime.Now, save the time in a variable, then Call it after a second again, save that too and look how many clicks where made?
If that's the trick, it's easier than i thought o.O

Comment: You will need some list variable for that. Maybe: List<DateTime> lstClicks; then you Add to it on click lstClicks.Add(DateTime.Now). lstClicks.Count will be number of times button was clicked. And for the clicks per second that is simple math, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a timer that every 1000 milliseconds checks the value of _klicks, saves it in your file and sets it back to 0

```
void main(){
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = 1000; // 1000 miliseconds = 1 second
    timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer.Enabled = true;
}
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do what you need
    var clicks = _klicks;
    // method to save clicks to the file
    _klicks = 0;
    return clicks;
}
```

This is if you do not need to record when the clicks happened, in that case use the suggestions in the comments.

Comment: It's worth noting that timers only guarantee that the event won't be fired in _less_ time than specified, but the actual interval may be longer. The shorter the specified interval, the more obvious the effect of other processes, threads, the system tick interval, ... delaying the execution of the event code.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an average, you should save the start time of the period over which you are averaging the clicks, so you can subtract it from the end time (which might be `DateTime.Now`).

Then you can calculate the average thus:

```
clicksPerSecond = _klicks / (_startTime - _endTime).TotalSeconds
```

This works because the DateTime subtraction operator returns a TimeSpan.